# Talend - How to get tFlowToIterate size and tFileInputRegex size?

Tags: talend

Good day,

I have component `tFileInputRegex` and `tFlowToIterate` to read data from a text file, I saw there are number of row record being process as follow:

[image]

Which is 3412 rows, may I know how can I get this value in `tJava_2` ?

currently I am using `_NB_LINE` but getting null:

```
System.out.println("total is " + (Integer)globalMap.get("tFileInputRegex_1_NB_LINE"));

System.out.println("total2 is " + (Integer)globalMap.get("tFlowToIterate_2_NB_LINE"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, tJava_2 executes within the iteration, i.e. once for each row. In that component, you can use **globalMap.get("tFlowToIterate_2_CURRENT_ITERATION").toString()** to get the number of rows processed so far. Please note that instead of casting it to Integer you need to convert it to a string as shown above in order to output it the way you do.
If you need the total number of rows, you can use **globalMap.get("tFileInputRegex_1_NB_LINE").toString()** - but it is only available after the end of the loop, which means the component where you access it needs to be connected to tFileInputRegex_1 via OnSubjobOk trigger.